# Using a C macro within a makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a shell script that will create a version information header file, version.h, which looks like

```
echo -e "\
#pragma once\n\
\n\
#include \"build_config.h\"\n\
\n\
\n\
#define COMMIT_REVISION                 \"${GIT_HEAD^^}\"\n\
#define COMMIT_FIRST_FOUR_BYTES         0x$(cut -c 1-8 <<< ${GIT_HEAD^^})\n\
#define CHECKOUT_SHA                    \"${CHECKOUT_SHA}\"\n\
#define CURRENT_SHA                     \"${CURRENT_SHA}\"\n\
#define DATE_OF_SHA                     \"${DATE_OF_SHA}\"\n\
#define BUILD_TYPE                      \"${BUILD_TYPE}\"\n\
\n\
#define BINARY_BASE_NAME               BUILD_TYPE \"_\" DATE_OF_SHA \"_\" CURRENT_SHA\n\" > ${1}
```

The environment variables used in the script are set during the execution of the script file.  For instance, `GIT_HEAD="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"`

The resulting header file the script creates looks like

```
#pragma once

#include "build_config.h"


#define COMMIT_REVISION                 "D70B1A73915F11BF5BF3A9D531BF57BA3D58CD73"
#define COMMIT_FIRST_FOUR_BYTES         0xD70B1A73
#define CHECKOUT_SHA                    "d70b1a73"
#define CURRENT_SHA                     "d70b1a7391"
#define DATE_OF_SHA                     "220621"
#define BUILD_TYPE                      "E"

#define BINARY_BASE_NAME               BUILD_TYPE CONTROLLER_CHIP_ID_CHAR CONTROLLER_CHIP_VERSION_CHAR DATE_OF_SHA "_" CURRENT_SHA
```

Within a makefile is there a way to use the macro BINARY_BASE_NAME within a target recipe?  Something like

```
bin/$(BINARY_BASE_NAME): bin/binary_object.o version.h
  $(V)cp bin/object.o bin/$(BINARY_BASE_NAME)
```

Would I need to export BINARY_BASE_NAME as an environment variable?  Can the makefile use the macro directly?

Comment: Your shell script is bogus (the final double-quote should probably not be escaped) and, more important, it is not consistent with the example header file you show. Where do these `CONTROLLER_CHIP_ID_CHAR` and `CONTROLLER_CHIP_VERSION_CHAR` in the header file come from? There is nothing like this in your script. Moreover your script separates the 3 macros that form `BINARY_BASE_NAME` by underscores but your example header file does not. Please provide a consistent example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing MadScientist's approach one step further you could generate a real piece of C code that prints this macro, compile it, execute it and redirect the output to the included Makefile. Simplified demo:

The simplified `version.h`:

```c
#define CURRENT_SHA         "d70b1a7391"
#define DATE_OF_SHA         "220621"
#define BUILD_TYPE          "E"

#define BINARY_BASE_NAME    BUILD_TYPE DATE_OF_SHA "_" CURRENT_SHA
```

The `Makefile` file:

```
include version.mk

define C_code
#include <stdio.h>
#include "$<"

int main(void) {
  printf("BINARY_BASE_NAME := %s\n", BINARY_BASE_NAME);
  return 0;
}

endef
export C_code

version.mk : version.h
    printf '%s\n' "$$C_code" > "$@.c"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o "$@.exe" "$@.c"
    "./$@.exe" > "$@"

.PHONY: all clean

all:
    @printf '%s\n' "$(BINARY_BASE_NAME)"

clean:
    rm -f version.mk.c version.mk.exe version.mk
```

And then:

```
$ make all
printf '%s\n' "$C_code" > "version.mk.c"
cc  -o "version.mk.exe" "version.mk.c"
"./version.mk.exe" > "version.mk"
E220621_d70b1a7391

$ cat version.mk.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "version.h"

int main(void) {
  printf("BINARY_BASE_NAME := %s\n", BINARY_BASE_NAME);
  return 0;
}

$ cat version.mk
BINARY_BASE_NAME := E220621_d70b1a7391

$ make clean
rm -f version.mk.c version.mk.exe version.mk
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  Make is not a C compiler, and a header file is not a makefile: make can't parse C code.

You could try to play a trick like, write a C file that included the above file then simply assigned it, and only run that C file through the preprocessor and not the compiler.  It would be kind of a hack.  Something like this MIGHT work:

```
# trick to get a variable $S that contains a single space
E :=
S := $E $E

include version.mk
_basename := $(subst ",,$(subst $S,,$(_basename)))

version.mk : version.h
        (echo '#include "$<"'; echo '_basename := BINARY_BASE_NAME') > $@.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E $@.c > $@
```

it *might* work.

**ETA**

Just to promote my comment below: the best way to do this is to either write another shell script that generates the makefile info like `version.mk`, or else enhance the shell script that creates `version.h` so that it also writes the same information to a file `version.mk`.  That would be a lot safer and more reliable.

Comment: _it might work_ ... as long as none of the macros contain spaces (e.g. `#define BUILD_TYPE "E F"`). But considering the use of `BINARY_BASE_NAME` in the OP we can probably exclude this.

Comment: Yes.  I said it was "kind of a hack".  Really, that's probably underselling it and it should be "a total hack" :).  If I were doing it I would just create a second shell script that would write out a `version.mk` for makefiles containing the same content as `version.h`.  Or, enhance the existing `version.h`-generating script to also write out `version.mk`.

Comment: We could also generate a real piece of C code that prints this macro, compile it, execute it and redirect the output to the included Makefile.

Comment: Yes, good point.  This might be the better way since I now notice that some of the values in `BINARY_BASE_NAME` are not defined here, and presumably come from the `build_config.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell script creates a header, why not make it also create a Makefile snippet that gets included by your main Makefile?

```
echo "BINARY_BASE_NAME := ${BUILD_TYPE}_${DATE_OF_SHA}_${CURRENT_SHA}" > makefile.inc
```

Then use a GNU make `include makefile.inc` directive.

Comment: This would work only in "simple" cases where the shell script has access to all bits. But if the header file generated by the script imports some macros from an included other header file, this would not work. And it seems to be the case (see the `#include "build_config.h"`, and the `CONTROLLER_CHIP_ID_CHAR` or `CONTROLLER_CHIP_VERSION_CHAR` macros) in the example of generated header file (but the shown script and the shown generated header file are not consistent).